# How to make Website working in all Resolutions?

Tags: html, css, resolution

I have made a Website which looks good in my Computer but It just Messes up on other computers with lower Resolution. Though I have used %tage in CSS, but still it Completely Mess up on resolutions like 1024x768 etc.

What Can I do about it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check out the [CSS Media Queries](http://css-tricks.com/css-media-queries/)

Or can go for [Different Stylesheets for Differently Sized Browser Windows](http://css-tricks.com/resolution-specific-stylesheets/)

Comment: But I think that isnt supported by all browsers isnt it

Comment: @Johnson: Current version of Firefox, Safari (including Mobile), Chrome, and Opera are all supporting it. Internet Explorer 9 will be supporting it, but 8 and below do not. You can check out this article to deal with IE: http://css-tricks.com/resolution-specific-stylesheets/ or use different style sheets for different resolutions :)

Comment: I have got Something Like Same Problem of a Sidebar, The Thing vanishes when the Resolution Changes to Something Smaller, Using Different Stylesheet will work?

Comment: It should, you can try that out, check out the article i have posted above :)